# PrototypeJS loop won't run

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a loop which won't run using Prototype + Scriptaculous.  It runs once for the first object in my array then stops.

```
var myMessages = new Object();
        myMessages = ['success','info','warning','error']; // define the messages types      
        function hideAllMessages()
        {
                 var messagesHeights = new Array(); // this array will store height for each

enter code here


        // This one runs just once for the first item in the array
                 var i = 0;
                 myMessages.each(function(element) {
                    alert(element);
                    messagesHeights[i] = $('.' + element).getHeight();
                    i++;
                    $$('.' + element + ' message').invoke('hide');
                 });


                 //This won't run at all===============================
                 for (var index = 0; index < myMessages.length; index++)
                 {
                        messagesHeights[index] = $('.' + myMessages[index]).getHeight();
                        $('x').hide(); 
                        //$('.' + myMessages[i]).css('top', -messagesHeights[i]); //move element outside viewport     
                 }
        }
```

Comment: Look at your browser's console. What error messages are there? I bet you have a problem with assigning to the array `messagesHeights` that doesn't have a length yet.

Comment: @clockworkgeek - You're correct that he probably has an error message, but it is most likely that `$('.' + element)` is returning null. Assigning to an array in that manner is allowed.

Comment: You're quite right. `element.getHeight()` is adequate on it's own. There are way more problems with the entire snippet, there is no point in keeping the heights as an array to being with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a prototype user, but here's what I see so far:

`$` is for IDs. I believe you need `$$` here:

```
$$('.' + element)
```

This returns an Array, so I think you need `invoke()` like this:

```
$$('.' + element).invoke('getHeight');
```

Also, `.each()` passes the index as the second argument to the callback, so you don't need to maintain your own `i`.

```
myMessages.each(function(element, i) {
```

Also, this:

```
$$('.' + element + ' message')
```

...would seem to be looking for elements with the *tag* named `message`. I assume you want a class instead.

```
$$('.' + element + ' .message').invoke('hide');
```

Comment: [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ANQ3c/). I removed the `for` loop since it seemed to just be replicating the `.each()`. But it seems to have the same issues with `$` vs `$$`.